Get half-day trading hours with Bloomberg API
I'm having trouble getting via the Bloomberg API in Python the trading hours on any given day. And more importantly, the opening and closing time of a half trading day like 2024-12-24.
I tried with CALENDAR_HOLIDAYS, TRADING_HOLIDAYS as fields and many different securities.
Do you have any idea of the securities, fields and possible overrides to enter in the query?
Thanks in advance.
